# Как синхрониировать 3 потока C#

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Есть задача. Учебная, так что вопросы оптимальности решения отходят на второй план.
Есть 3 потока, работу которых нужно синхронизировать.
Первый поток собирает информацию о файлах и папках. Работает циклично и рекурсивно.
Найдя информацию,  он должен остановиться и дать  потокам  2  и 3 записать ее в файл и память. Когда потоки 2 и 3 закончат запись, поток 1 возобновляет работу и ищет следующий файл(папку).
Потоков должно быть 3. Писать каждый найденный файл в новом потоке - не вариант.
    Вопросы следующие:
    1. Какой механизм лучше применить для синхронизации потоков: AutoResetEvent (свой для каждого из двух потоков -  см. код), ManualResetEvent или Semaphore.
    2. Как нужно исправить код, чтобы потоки запускались и останавливались когда нужно? Буду благодарен за пояснения почему именно так, потому что с методами Set(), Reset(), Wait() я игрался долго, но безуспешно.
    3. Как правильно организовать остановку вторичных потоков после окончания работы первичного? Я приравнял null первичный поток, но думаю, что это не лучшая идея.
   4. И был бы благодарен за разъяснение как решать аналогичные задачи в нормальных, не учебных проектах.
   5. Нужно ли   в данном примере проводить считывание информации вторичными потоками  в критической секции? Как я предполагаю, информация в процессе считывания не поменяется, так как основной поток ждет завершения вторичных, и необходимости в критической секции нет.

Код:

```
private Queue<Nested3> collection;
        static int counter=100;
        object locked;
        Thread SearcherThread;
        Thread Handler1Thread;
        Thread Handler2Thread;
        static WaitHandle[] events;

        private class Nested3
        {
            public int Val;
            public bool IsHandled;

        public Nested3(int val)
            {
                this.Val = val;
                IsHandled = false;
            }
       }

        public ARETest()
        {
            collection = new Queue<Nested3>();
            events = new WaitHandle[] { new AutoResetEvent(false), new AutoResetEvent(false) };
            SearcherThread = new Thread(Searcher);
            SearcherThread.Start();
            Handler1Thread = new Thread(Handler1);
            Handler2Thread = new Thread(Handler2);
            locked = new object();
        }

       private void Searcher()
        {  
                // Очередь для двух задач в двух разных потоках. 
         ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(Handler1), events[0]);
         ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(Handler2), events[1]);
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(2);  // имитация поиска
                Monitor.Enter(locked); // применение класса Monitor для создания критической секции обусловлено условием задачи
                collection.Enqueue(new Nested3(++counter)); // Найден первый пакет информации для записи вторичными потками
                Monitor.Exit(locked);
                (events[0] as AutoResetEvent).Set(); // запуск вторичных потоков
                (events[1] as AutoResetEvent).Set();

                (events[0] as AutoResetEvent).Reset(); // сброс в несигнальное состояние
                (events[1] as AutoResetEvent).Reset();

                // Ожидание пока все задачи завершаться.
                WaitHandle.WaitAll(events);

                Monitor.Enter(locked); // Очистка очереди от записанной информации
                collection.Dequeue();
                Monitor.Exit(locked);

            if (i<2) Searcher();   // Рекурсивный вызов                  
            }

            SearcherThread = null;

            // Запуск  последнего прохода цикла  вторичными потоками
            (events[0] as AutoResetEvent).Set(); 
            (events[1] as AutoResetEvent).Set();

        }

    private  void Handler1(object state)
    { 
        var auto = (AutoResetEvent)state;

        do
        {
        auto.WaitOne(); // здесь я хочу чтобы потоки ждали сигнала от первичного потока
        Thread.Sleep(15); // имитация записи в файл
        auto.Set(); // Здесь вторичный поток должен дать первичному сигнал, что он закончил итерацию 
        } while (SearcherThread != null);
    }

    private void Handler2(Object state)  // работает аналогично предыдущему методу, но с другой задержкой
    {
        var auto = (AutoResetEvent)state;
        do
        {
         auto.WaitOne(); // здесь я хочу чтобы потоки ждали сигнала от первичного потока
        Thread.Sleep(15); // имитация записи в файл
        auto.Set(); // Здесь вторичный поток должен дать первичному сигнал, что он закончил итерацию 
        } while (SearcherThread != null);


    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А нужна ли Вам здесь вообще прямая работа с потоками? Для выполнения нескольких задач параллельно можно использовать высокоуровневый приметив `Parallel.Invoke`.

```
static int counter=100;

private class Nested3 {
    public int Val;
    public bool IsHandled;

    public Nested3(int val) {
        this.Val = val;
        IsHandled = false;
    }
}

private void Searcher() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        Thread.Sleep(2); // имитация поиска
        Nested3 currentItem = new Nested3(++counter);
        Parallel.Invoke(() => Handler1(currentItem), () => Handler2(currentItem));
    }
}

private void Handler1(Nested3 currentItem) {
    Thread.Sleep(15); // имитация записи в файл
}

private void Handler2(Nested3 currentItem) {
    Thread.Sleep(15); // имитация записи в файл
}
```

Если важно использовать именно `WaitHandle`, то можно поступить следующим образом:

```
private AutoResetEvent done = new AutoResetEvent(false);

private void Searcher() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        Thread.Sleep(2); // имитация поиска
        Nested3 currentItem = new Nested3(++counter);
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ => {
            Handler2(currentItem);
            done.Set();
        }); // одно из заданий выполняем в пуле потоков
        Handler1(currentItem); // а другое выполняем в текущем потоке
        done.WaitOne(); // ждём завершения задания, которое отдали пулу потоков
    }
}
```

Comment: Использование производных от WaitHandle - условие задачи. То, что предложили Вы хорошо подходит для решения, и скорее всего я буду это использовать в проектах, но в условии было именно использование WaitHandle  и его производных.

Comment: @foxhound Дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за ответ. Такое решение мне в голову не пришло.
В общем, в итоге метод Searcher() выглядит так.

```
private void Searcher()
        {  

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(2);
                Monitor.Enter(locked);
                collection.Enqueue(new Nested3(++counter)); // теперь очередь можно заменить на единичный объект класса
                Monitor.Exit(locked);

                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ =>
                {
                    Handler2();
                    (events[1] as AutoResetEvent).Set();
                });

                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ =>
                {
                    Handler1();
                    (events[0] as AutoResetEvent).Set();
                });

                WaitHandle.WaitAll(events);

                Console.WriteLine("Доджался");

                Monitor.Enter(locked);
                collection.Dequeue();
                Monitor.Exit(locked);


                Console.WriteLine("Поиск отработан"); 
                Console.WriteLine();
                if (counter<105) Searcher(); // рекурсивыный  вызов
            }
        }
```